# How to bind a drop down with a model property while containing the list items of that drop down?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am stuck in a problem, I have retrieved all the value for a drop down in a view bag and want to display them at run time. I have achieved it by using the following code for the controller

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var categoryList = new PersonalApp();
        SelectList catList = new SelectList(categoryList.GetAffinity().ToList(), "ClientName", "AffinityNum");
        ViewBag.categoryList = catList;
        return View();
    }
```

and the following code for the view

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("index", "Home"))
{
@Html.DropDownList("categoryList", "Branch Type")
}
```

It really works but now I want to bind it with a model now. I have use the following code for this:

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(model=>model.AffinityNum, "categoryList", "BranchType")
```

But it gives me an error as CategoryList cannot be used as a parameter with the above code. How will I get this resolved as I can have all the values of a dropdown in the categorylist and I can bind it with a model property affinityNum with it as well.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your model should have an `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` property that will hold the values:

```
public class PersonalApp
{
    public string AffinityNum { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> CategoryList { get; set; }
}
```

that you will populate in your controller action and pass to the view:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var model = new PersonalApp();
    var categories = categoryList.GetAffinity().ToList();
    SelectList catList = new SelectList(categories, "ClientName", "AffinityNum");
    model.CategoryList = catList;
    return View(model);
}
```

and finally in your strongly typed view you will use this property to bind the dropdown list to:

```
@model PersonalApp
...
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.AffinityNum, Model.CategoryList, "BranchType")
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try;
@Html.DropDownListFor(model=>model.AffinityNum, (SelectList)ViewBag.categoryList)